# Exception while using pushy to send push Notification in Linux

Tags: java, linux, netty, glibc, pushy

We are using Pushy for sending APNs push notifications.

I am using Java 7

**Part of build.gradle :**

```
compile "com.relayrides:pushy:0.9"
compile "io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:1.1.33.Fork24"
```

It working all fine in windows with tomcat. I am able to send push notification successfully.

Now when I deploy the same in Websphere (in linux box), I get below exception

**Logs:**

[1/31/17 14:43:56:199 GMT] 0000005a SystemOut     O 2017-01-31 14:43:56,198 DEBUG server.startup : 1 io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64', trying next name...

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnetty-tcnative-linux-x86_641121758415883595555.so (/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /tmp/libnetty-tcnative-linux-x86_641121758415883595555.so))**
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1235)
   at java.lang.System.load(System.java:521)

[1/31/17 14:43:56:203 GMT] 0000005a SystemOut     O 2017-01-31 14:43:56,202 DEBUG server.startup : 1 io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora', trying other loading mechanism.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora (Not found in java.library.path)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1235)

[1/31/17 14:43:56:205 GMT] 0000005a SystemOut     O 2017-01-31 14:43:56,204 DEBUG server.startup : 1 io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora', trying next name...

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora (Not found in java.library.path)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1235)

[1/31/17 14:43:56:222 GMT] 0000005a SystemOut     O 2017-01-31 14:43:56,221 DEBUG server.startup : 1 io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library '/tmp/libnetty-tcnative7114082995236005555.so', trying other loading mechanism.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnetty-tcnative7114082995236005555.so (/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /tmp/libnetty-tcnative7114082995236005555.so))
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1235)

Please help.

Comment: Is glibc version 2.7 installed on the machine?

Comment: @Henry : Its glibc 2.5

Comment: Ok, then you may need to upgrade it.